# What is difference between unspecified no of arguments and variable no of arguments passed to a C function?

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define L 11

int oo1(){
printf("oooooo\n");
}

int oo2(int C ,...)
{
 //some code here
 printf("in oo2\n");
}
int main(void){
 oo1();
 oo1(1,4,7,"f");
 oo2(2);
 oo2(2,5,7,3,11);
 printf("%d\n",L);
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
oooooo

oooooo

in oo2

in oo2

11
```

This code has 2 functions oo1 and oo2 . oo2 is a function that accepts variable number of arguments . However , oo1 accepts variable or any number of arguments too as it seems . What is the difference between these two and how do they work ? Any link or reference would be helpful too if this seems too obvious . Thanks .

Comment: Actually, does `An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters.` makes `oo1(1,4,7,"f");` invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that it’s unspecified what happens for `oo1`.

> oo1 accepts variable or any number of arguments too as it seems

The C standard does not guarantee this. In fact, all the C standard says on this regard is that a function *definition* with an empty argument list is compatible with a function declaration with an argument list of `void` (ISO/IEC 9899 6.9.1, footnote 162).

That is, the function definition

```
int oo1() {…}
```

Is compatible with the prototype declaration

```
int oo1(void);
```

In other words, the only safe thing you may do is call `oo1` without arguments. But the C compiler is not obliged to diagnose violations of this. That said, a modern C compiler *will* warn:

> warning: too many arguments in call to 'oo1'

Heed this warning. You mustn’t call `oo1` with any arguments.